# How to change the background color of a HTML page for printing?

Tags: html, css, printing, background, media-queries

I want to make my website properly printable. The `body` of the HTML document has a background color other than white.

```
body {
  background-color: #F8F6F6;
}
```

The problem is that some parts of the background of the *printed* page (the margins and the part after the document end) are white as shown below:

[image]

How can I change the color of these areas?

---

### **Edit (clarification):**

I want to change the color of white areas in the picture to `#F8F6F6`, not the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

> [css printing](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/css/css_printing.htm)

```
   @media print{
     body {
       background-color: #FFFFFF;
     }
   }
```

Comment: No. This changes the background color of the `body`, not the color of the white areas which are outside the `body`. In other words, I want to change the color of white areas in the picture to `#F8F6F6`, not the opposite. This is my question.

Comment: Get different colored paper. The problem here, as I see it, is more so about ink usage. It's not the answer you want, but you really should not be using ink to color an entire page, especially when that color is just vaguely, off-white. Margins are set by the computer/printer, so I don't think you can force them to be standard for your users.